# disable cursor/editing but keep ability to focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway to achieve this that works cross-browser? (Keeping solutions to pure JavaScript, HTML, and CSS) I'm using JQuery, so JS in that would be best.

(disabled="disabled" doesn't allow focus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled`, like `<input readonly="readonly" />`

Comment: I hadn't come across `readonly` before. +1 for teaching me something new =)